# How do I SetDelayed $Assumptions

Tags: evaluation, assumptions, assignment

For some reason,

```
$Assumptions := (Print["y"]; x > 0)
```

evaluates the RHS immediately.

I have code in which `$Assumptions` dynamically changes, and where the RHS is complicated for general cases and takes a long time to evaluate.  So I need to delay its evaluation until it is needed.  What can I do to delay evaluation?

Comment: I noticed too that `$Assumptions` is special.  The values you set are checked immediately.  Try e.g. `$Assumptions =.` and you'll see that after this it is still set to `True`.  Try `$Assumptions = {False}`, and notice the warning message "Warning: one or more assumptions evaluated to False."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I somehow forgot but Szabolcs reminded me many System variables (typically with names beginning with `$`) check the values they are set to, e.g.:

```
$MinPrecision := -6

$MinPrecision
```

> \$MinPrecision::precset: Cannot set \$MinPrecision to -6; value must be a non-negative number or Infinity. >>
>
> ```
> 0
> ```

In this case the check causes evaluation you do not want.  You can bypass it by modifying the `OwnValues` directly.  A helper function to make this cleaner:

```
SetAttributes[mySet, HoldAll]
mySet[LHS_Symbol, RHS_] := (OwnValues[LHS] = {HoldPattern[LHS] :> RHS};)
```

Now:

```
mySet[$Assumptions, Print["y"]; x > 0]  (* nothing prints *)
```

and:

```
Refine[{x < 0, x == 0, x > 0}]
```

> y
>
> ```
> {False, False, True}
> ```

Also:

```
mySet[$Assumptions, Print["y = ", y]; x > y]

y = 1;
Refine[{x > 1, x > 2, x > 3}]

y = 2;
Refine[{x > 1, x > 2, x > 3}]

y = 3;
Refine[{x > 1, x > 2, x > 3}]
```

> y = 1
>
> ```
> {True, x > 2, x > 3}
> ```
>
> y = 2
>
> ```
> {True, True, x > 3}
> ```
>
> y = 3
>
> ```
> {True, True, True}
> ```

Comment: "I don't yet understand why your assignment triggers additional evaluation of the RHS" <- Try `x=-1; $Assumptions := {x>0}`.  I think this explains why.

Comment: @Szabolcs Ah, I completely forgot about those checks; thanks.  I see that you did not vote for this answer; do you consider it dangerous?

Comment: I forget about voting sometimes.  But I thought moderators cannot see who voted and who didn't.  About the dangers: I don't know. It works, but I won't be very surprised if something strange happens.  But it probably won't.  You should get some sleep BTW.  Isn't it 4 am there?

Comment: @Szabolcs There were zero votes of any kind at the time of my comment; it did not require a vast leap of deduction to conclude that you had not voted on it. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

To change the assumptions dynamically, this can be used:

```
$Assumptions := b
b = {c > 0};
Refine[{c < 0, c == 0, c > 0}]

b = {c < 0};
Refine[{c < 0, c == 0, c > 0}]
```

If you need to evaluate the `Print` every time, this can be used:

```
$Assumptions := Evaluate[b]
b = {c > 0, Unevaluated@Print[kount]};
kount = 1;
Refine[{c < 0, c == 0, c > 0}]
kount = 2;
Refine[{c < 0, c == 0, c > 0}]

b = {c < 0, Unevaluated@Print[kount]};
kount = 3;
Refine[{c < 0, c == 0, c > 0}]
kount = 4;
Refine[{c < 0, c == 0, c > 0}]
```

Beware, however, that using `Print` in the assumptions could have unintended consequences.  `Print` returns `Null`, so the effect will be that `Null` will be assumed to be `True`, as illustrated here:

```
$Assumptions = {Print["beware"]};
Refine[Null]

(* beware *)

(* True *)
```